# Dramatic Python speed difference between Linux/Flask and Windows/Flask

Tags: python, windows, jboss, flask

I have written the following code to drastically optimize the development cycle of our developers that work under Linux... What it does, is that it serves static content directly from the disk, and only forwards REST-ful requests to their running instance of JBOSS.

In other words...

- instead of hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8080/APPNAME` from their browsers, to speak to the locally running JBOSS...
- they hit `http://127.0.0.1:4040/APPNAME` - which only speaks to JBOSS 
  for the RESTful webservices, and provides static content (.html/.css/.js) directly from the disk.

This makes their development cycle dramatically faster, because after compiling their TypeScript code to JavaScript, they just hit "Refresh" on the browser, and the 
tiny forwarder serves the new versions of the files. They don't need to perform full JBOSS builds, generate .ear that contain the updated .js, and deploy to their local JBOSS.

For e.g. one or two file edits, this provides 2 (maybe 3!) orders of magnitute speedier tests - it's basically "compile TypeScript, reload in browser".

I then tried the same script with developers that work under 64bit Windows, installing the native 64-bit Windows Python, then setuptools, and then 'easy_install flask'.

... and to my utter despair, found that the script runs 20-30x times slower under Windows!

Is this a limitation of Flask, or is there something I can do?

Thanks for any help.

The code:

```
# Detection of some global variable content from environent and config files
...

# And the tiny forwarder:
from flask import (Flask, make_response, request, send_from_directory)

appMain = Flask(
    __name__, static_url_path='/'+g_appName, static_folder=g_staticPath)
appMain.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024


@appMain.route(
    "/"+g_appName+"/",
    methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return send_from_directory(g_staticPath, 'index.html')


@appMain.route(
    "/"+g_appName+"/rest/<unused_entityName>/<unused_endpoint>",
    methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def genericForwarder(unused_entityName, unused_endpoint):
    request.url = request.url.encode('ascii')
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" + \
          re.sub(r'^http.*:4040/', '', request.url)
    try:
        print g_green + "\nRedirecting:\n    " + g_normal + request.url,
        print g_green + "\nto:\n    " + g_normal + url,

        method = request.method
        cookieData = ""
        prefix = ""
        for key, value in request.cookies.items():
            cookieData += prefix + key + '=' + value
            prefix = "&"

        print g_yellow + "\nCookies >>> " + g_normal + cookieData

        handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
        headers = {}
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        if cookieData:
            headers['Cookie'] = cookieData
        r = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers, )
        r.add_data(request.data)
        r.get_method = lambda: method
        #if 'zekmSave' in request.url:
        #    import ipdb
        #    ipdb.set_trace()

        f = opener.open(r)
        response = f.read()
        resp = make_response(response, 200)
        respCookies = f.headers.get('set-cookie', '')
        print g_cyan + "Cookies <<< " + g_normal + respCookies
        if respCookies:
            resp.headers['Set-Cookie'] = respCookies
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    except Exception, e:
        message = e.fp.read()
        print g_red, "Exception:", str(e), g_normal, "\n"
        print g_yellow, e.code, message, g_normal
        resp = make_response(message, e.code)
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    appMain.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=4040)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seriously tempted to answer my own question with a plain *"Windows sucks"*, but that would be too general an aphorism. I can only guess that the speed difference is related to the glacial spawn-speed that Windows "forks" processes (1-2 orders of magnitude slower than any UNIX OS) - so if Flask is following the usual fork/exec pattern in UNIX web servers, that could explain the problem.

How did I cope?

Simple: I updated my build script so that once the build completes, it automatically finds the local folder where JBoss "explodes" the deployed .ear ($JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs/...)  and then `rsync`s the newly generated .js/.css/.html files inside that folder. Thankfully, CygWin's rsync works fast enough even under Windows, which makes the build cycle instantaneous even for my Windows-locked brethren: rebuild, and then Ctrl-R in their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have visual studio installed, the Flask module won't be compiled as C and will be pure python on Windows.  Which will make it slower.

Comment: Visual Studio was installed - I just did "pip install flask" from a DOS prompt. Is there an additional option I should have passed?